# React js break when match happens

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am wanting to stop a loop that i have when it matches a condition but its just not breaking ive tried try catch loops with throw e and throw new typeerror but its just not breaking how do i get it to break here is the code i want to break

```
LoginAuth = (Res) => {
    try {
        if (Res.username === this.state.Username && Res.password === this.state.Password) {
            return (
                this.setState({
                    isLoggedIn: true,
                }, function () {

                }),
                this.hideModal()
            );
        } else {
            console.log("Gets to login auth and false");
        }
}
```

I want to make it stop when the user input in state.username and state.password are equal to the one in the variable Res but i cant get it to stop looping how do i do this.

this is the function that calls this one

```
CheckLoginAuth() {
    console.log("gets to check login auth");
    console.log(this.state.AuthRes);
    console.log("Username=" + this.state.Username);
    console.log("Password=" + this.state.Password);
    var self = this;
    this.props.AuthRes.forEach(function (Res) {
        return (
            console.log("ID=" + Res.id),
            console.log("Username=" + Res.username),
            console.log("Password=" + Res.password),
            self.LoginAuth(Res)
        );
    });
}
```

edit

```
CheckLoginAuth() {
    console.log("gets to check login auth");
    console.log(this.state.AuthRes);
    console.log("Username=" + this.state.Username);
    console.log("Password=" + this.state.Password);
    this.props.AuthRes.some(function (Res) {
        console.log("ID=" + Res.id);
        console.log("Username=" + Res.username);
        console.log("Password=" + Res.password);
        if (Res.username === this.state.Username && Res.password === this.state.Password) {// the error is on this line saying it doesnt know what Username or Password are in the state
            return (
                this.setState({
                    isLoggedIn: true,
                }, function () {
                }),
                this.hideModal()
            );
        } else {
            console.log("Gets to login auth and false");
        }
    });
}
```

error is Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

```
LoginAuth = (Res) => {
    if (Res.username === this.state.Username && Res.password === this.state.Password) {
        return (
            this.setState({
                isLoggedIn: true,
            }, function () {
            }),
            this.hideModal()
        );
    } else {
        console.log("Gets to login auth and false");
    }
}
CheckLoginAuth() {
    console.log("gets to check login auth");
    console.log(this.state.AuthRes);
    console.log("Username=" + this.state.Username);
    console.log("Password=" + this.state.Password);
    var self = this;
    this.props.AuthRes.every(function (Res) {
        console.log("ID=" + Res.id);
        console.log("Username=" + Res.username);
        console.log("Password=" + Res.password);
        return (
            self.LoginAuth(Res)
        );
    });
}
```

loops through but stops on the first one weather its true or false

Comment: Are you using promises there? If yes, then you need return exception in Promise.reject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by making it break

my code was

```
LoginAuth = (Res) => {
if (Res.username === this.state.Username && Res.password === this.state.Password) {
    return (
        this.setState({
            isLoggedIn: true,
        }, function () {
        }),
        this.hideModal()
    );
} else {
    console.log("Gets to login auth and false");
}
}
CheckLoginAuth() {
    console.log("gets to check login auth");
    console.log(this.state.AuthRes);
    console.log("Username=" + this.state.Username);
    console.log("Password=" + this.state.Password);
    var self = this;
    this.props.AuthRes.every(function (Res) {
        console.log("ID=" + Res.id);
        console.log("Username=" + Res.username);
        console.log("Password=" + Res.password);
        return (
            self.LoginAuth(Res)
        );
    });
}
```

it is now

```
LoginAuth = (Res) => {
    if (Res.username === this.state.Username && Res.password === this.state.Password) {
            this.setState({
                isLoggedIn: true,
            })

            this.hideModal();
            return true;
    } else {
        console.log("Gets to login auth and false");
        return null;
    }
}
CheckLoginAuth() {
    console.log("gets to check login auth");
    console.log(this.state.AuthRes);
    console.log("Username=" + this.state.Username);
    console.log("Password=" + this.state.Password);
    var self = this;
    this.props.AuthRes.some(function (Res) {
        console.log("ID=" + Res.id);
        console.log("Username=" + Res.username);
        console.log("Password=" + Res.password);
        return self.LoginAuth(Res);
    });
}
```

i wasn't returning a truthy value or a falsy value

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to stop execution of a `forEach()`. In fact, the [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) states:

> There is no way to stop or break a `forEach()` loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the `forEach()` method is the wrong tool. Use a plain loop instead. If you are testing the array elements for a predicate and need a Boolean return value, you can use `every()` or `some()` instead.

So, as suggested, you could use [**`some()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead.

> `some()` executes the `callback` function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a *truthy* value (a value that becomes true when converted to a Boolean). If such an element is found, `some()` immediately returns `true`. Otherwise, `some()` returns `false`.

---

So your function could instead be written as:

```
this.props.AuthRes.some(function (Res) {
    return (
        console.log("ID=" + Res.id),
        console.log("Username=" + Res.username),
        console.log("Password=" + Res.password),
        self.LoginAuth(Res)
    );
});
```

this will stop the iteration once the callback returns true, or until you run out of elements to iterate through.

---

**Edit**

To solve the `Cannot read property 'state' of undefined` error, the simplest way is to use an arrow function:

```
this.props.AuthRes.some((Res) => {
```

Comment: Would i put my If statement inside checkLoginAuth cause it still loops through all if you type in the first one in the list

Comment: @andywilson, I'm not sure how your entire application works. So I cannot say exactly how and where certain code should go. All I can do is answer your question on how to break a loop once a condition is met. :)

Comment: @andywilson, if this answer was helpful to you please consider marking it as "accepted" and/or up-voting for visibility.

Comment: @Chirs it keeps looping over even though i have put the .some part and now it is giving me another error i will write the error in my edit

Comment: @andywilson, you need to make sure you return a truthy value when the condition is fulfilled.

Comment: So if i use .every instead it will loop through the first one and stop even if it is false why is this?